# Unit Testing for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, unit-testing

I am new to unit testing and am trying things out.

I created a view controller with 1 button (get sum), and 3 textfields (input 2 numbers and output the sum).

```
int aNum = [self.firstNumber.text intValue];
int bNum = [self.secondNumber.text intValue];

sum = aNum + bNum;
self.total.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", sum];
[self dismissKeyboard];
```

And my testing codes:

```
vc = [[TestingViewController alloc] init];
vc.firstNumber.text = @"1";
vc.secondNumber.text = @"2";

[vc getSum:nil];

STAssertTrue([vc.total.text isEqualToString:@"3"], @"total should be 3");
```

The test failed because I have tried to work with UI elements.

My questions is: is it possible to test with UI elements like this? How would I write a test to achieve this?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, testing UI element in unit tests is definitely possible.

Techniques for this and more (including testing code which relies on networks) is covered in Test-Driven iOS Development (Developer's Library) by Graham Lee is a great resource:
[http://www.amazon.com/Test-Driven-iOS-Development-Developers-Library/dp/0321774183](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321774183)

Could be that the view isn't getting loaded. I had the same problem when I started with unit testing on iOS. Try calling [vc loadView]; after you init the viewcontroller.

```
vc = [[TestingViewController alloc] init];
[vc loadView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the NIB which is done by accessing the view (see [iOS' view lifecycle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html)):

```
vc = [[TestingViewController alloc] init];
// vc.firstNumber is nil right now, because the view isn't loaded
[vc view];
// vc.firstNumber now exists
vc.firstNumber.text = @"1";
vc.secondNumber.text = @"2";

[vc getSum:nil];

STAssertTrue([vc.total.text isEqualToString:@"3"], @"total should be 3");
```

Alternatively, if the view is part of a UIWindow hierarchy, you don't need to do this (ie - end-to-end testing)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to test a feature of your application while it runs. Do you understand the difference between unit tests and application tests? Did you read and obey the [documentation on application tests](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002143-CH3-SW6)? Are you running on the device?

Here's a helpful tutorial: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/12/sample-iphone-application-with-complete.html

Answer (score 0):

to test the UI, u can use javascript and that runs in Instruments.